# How to remove an HTML element in a target page with no ID's or class names, etc.?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, greasemonkey

I want to remove an element which has an XPath:

```
html/body/center/center/table/tbody/tr/td
```

I want to remove the `<table>` and its content.  I found some answers but they all need `id`, `class` name, etc.

The target page is like a flat board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that that is a ***precise***, ***exact*** XPath, then you can use `document.evaluate` to remove the table, like so:

```
var badTableEval = document.evaluate (
    "//body/center/center/table",
    document.documentElement,
    null,
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
    null
);

if (badTableEval  &&  badTableEval.singleNodeValue) {
    var badTable  = badTableEval.singleNodeValue;
    badTable.parentNode.removeChild (badTable);
}
```

---

---

---

Or use the equivalent jQuery.  Here it is in **a complete script**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

$("body > center:first > center:first > table:first").remove ();
```

jQuery has [a powerful collection of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and using jQuery will pay huge dividends in speed, ease, and robustness of scripting.

Comment: i think i will start to read about jquery it seems very simple
thanks again for your help 
Best Regards